# Wireless network card compatiblility

Tags: wireless-networking

The printer I want to buy is 802.11b/g/n wireless adaptor compatible, my PC wireless adapter is 802.11a/g/n. Will the printer work, and if so, will there be a degraded performance issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how you'll be connecting them – in a LAN, devices *only* connect to the access point, not directly to each other.

So you should be comparing the printer to your AP (router/modem/etc) instead. Comparing to your laptop's adapter is *only* useful if you're planning to use "WiFi Direct" printing. But here it is anyway:

- Both devices support the 2.4 GHz band (since they mention .11g which is 2.4-only), so they should be able to communicate directly.
- The fastest standard supported by both is 802.11n, although you'll probably be limited to 20 MHz, 1 stream, so I'd expect the maximum transfer speed to be ~40 Mbps. (Plenty for a printer.)